# nginx lua: os.execute waitpid() failed (10: No child processes)

Tags: nginx, lua

So, I'm trying to execute a script on every request. I know how that sounds, this is for development environment.

I've added this to my nginx config `access_by_lua_file "/opt/nginx/git-magic.lua";`

git-magic.lua contains `local status = os.execute('/opt/nginx/git-magic.sh')`

And git-magic.sh contains: `echo hello >> /tmp/git-magic`

**The issue is:**

Whenever I hit any URL, I get the following in the nginx error log: `2012/09/27 15:35:48 [alert] 3241#0: waitpid() failed (10: No child processes)`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: wow... I'm having the EXACT same problem, and thought I was going nuts... I'm looking hard to see if I can find an answer...

Comment: I am also having the same problem!!

Comment: Have you checked the obvious? Can nginx user access lua file? can nginx user write to /tmp/ ?

Comment: Lua can access git-magic.sh, git-magic.sh writes the right thing to /tmp/git-magic

Comment: See if there's an apparmor.d file for nginx.  I had a problem convincing dhcpd to run a file when an address is requested, because apparmor was blocking it.

Comment: 3 years on, any progress on this (other than the resty suggestion by Frederik?)

Answer (score 0):

The [lua-resty-shell](https://github.com/juce/lua-resty-shell) claims to solve this issue by supplying a non-blocking os.execute equivalent.